# How can I sort and do a search in mongodb spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I cannot sort my search results using Mongodb, I added a method query that uses findAllByorderByDateDesc()

I tried using "findAllByOrderByDateDesc() and it works if I'm not doing a search query but once I add the @Query annotation it stops sorting by dates.

Repository

```
@Repository
public interface WarrantiesRepository extends MongoRepository<WarrantyModel, String> {
    public Page<WarrantyModel> findAllByOrderByDateDesc(PageRequest pageRequest);

    @Query("{$text: {$search: ?0}}")
    public Page<WarrantyModel> findAllByOrderByDateDesc(String search, PageRequest pageRequest);
    public WarrantyModel getWarrantyById(String id);
    public WarrantyModel getWarrantyByCar(String car);
    public WarrantyModel getWarrantyByPart(String part);
    public WarrantyModel getWarrantyBypartNumber(String partNumber);
}
```

Controller

```
    @PostMapping("/warranties/search")
    public ModelAndView getLiveWarranties(@RequestBody String search, Model model) {
        input = search.substring(1, search.length()-1);
        if(search.length() == 2) {
            warranties = warrantiesRepository.findAllByOrderByDateDesc(PageRequest.of(currentPage, pageSize));
        } else {
            warranties = warrantiesRepository.findAllByOrderByDateDesc(search, PageRequest.of(currentPage, pageSize));
        }
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("warranties::search");
        mv.addObject("warranties", warranties);
        
        return mv;
    }
```

Model

```
@Component
@Document("Warranty")
public class WarrantyModel {
    
    @Id
    public String id;
    
    @TextIndexed
    public String car;
    @TextIndexed
    public String part;
    public String store;
    @TextIndexed
    public String partNumber;
    public String warranty;
    public LocalDate date;
    
Constructors/getter/setters
```

[Search Queries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f34EG.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior. By default all the methods of a '...Repository' are 'derived query methods' and Spring tries to map the implementation based on the method name (It will generate the queries for you).

Once you annotate a method with `@Query` annotation, Spring expects you to specify your own query and will not do any derivation on its own irrespective of the name of the method.

Check this article for more detailed explanation - [Spring Data MongoDB - Guide to the @Query Annotation](https://stackabuse.com/spring-data-mongodb-guide-to-the-query-annotation/)